# How to set up a PHP daemon?

Tags: php, linux, daemon

I will be writing my first daemon in php and I have a couple really basic questions that I need help with.

1. What packages need to be
   installed on my linux server and
   Does anything in PHP need to be
   enabled? So far I have gotten this -
   http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/download
2. Where on server do I save my
   daemon files?
3. I have a number of
   files that need to be included
   within the daemon that contain
   classes and functions for gathering
   emails and attachments through IMAP.
   All of these files are currently in
   my web public directory, how do I
   include these files within my daemon?

I think that is everything I need to get started.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. What packages need to be installed on my linux server and Does anything
>      in PHP need to be enabled? So far I
>      have gotten this -
>      http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/download

As long your php installation includes [sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) you'll be able to write any daemon.
Most of current php packages provides sockets support.
You need a shell access to be able to configure and execute your daemon, it won't be done by serving it as a web application.

I don't know about the package you mentioned but it's likely to be a way to make you easier to write and maintain your daemon.

> 2. Where on server do I save my daemon files?

Anywhere, you just need a shell access, you'll probably need root privileges, if you need to launch it on a port under 1024. Create a special user, eventualy make a jail, you'll probably be fine.

> 3. I have a number of files that need to be included within the daemon that
>      contain classes and functions for
>      gathering emails and attachments
>      through IMAP. All of these files are
>      currently in my web public directory,
>      how do I include these files within my
>      daemon?

Use a config file, such as a ini which is supported by PHP to specify a data directory and read from.

Further reading :

- [Create daemons in PHP](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/)
- [Daemons in PHP](http://www.hodulik.com/2005/08/01/daemons-in-php/)
- [phpsocketdaemon](http://code.google.com/p/phpsocketdaemon/) library

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I think I'm good on question #1, but still confused on #2. Can I save my daemon in my web root? Or, is it better to put it outside of the web root?

Comment: I'm not a sysadmin, but from a security point of view it should be better to put it outside, if your daemon becomes exploited, only itself and its data would compromised not the entire web directory.